# Flask SQLAlchemy enforce maximum length constraint on a column

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy with sqlite database.
This is a model I defined

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True)
    alias = db.Column(db.CHAR(1), unique=True)
    members = db.relationship('User', backref='members', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Role: {self.name}>'
```

When I try to add a new role in the python shell, like this:

```
>>> dummy = Role(name='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', alias='asdfghjk')
>>> db.session.add(dummy)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

it still allows me to do this even though the `String` has a length constraint of 10 characters and `CHAR` has a maximum length of 1. I would expect SQLAlchemy to throw an exception but it doesn't.

My question is why these constraints are not reinforced by SQLAlchemy? What is the correct/easy way to reinforce the constraints?
How much memory do these columns actually use to store information? For example, if the longest entry in the CHAR(1) column is 8 characters long, do ALL the other entries occupy the same amount of memory as the longest one?

Comment: How did you create your Table? Does your table actually have those data types?

Comment: @PGHE I defined the above model and used Flask-Migrate to upgrade the database. 'DB Browser for SQLite' on my mac shows the `name` column of type `VARCHAR(10)` and `alias` column of type `CHAR(1)`

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't have a `CHAR` type, when you declare `Char(1)` with SQLalchemy the SQLite `TEXT` type is used.

> TEXT is returned if the type name includes the string CHAR, CLOB or TEXT

Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html

You can also read that on SQLite documentation

> If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR",
> "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the
> type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT
> affinity.

source: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

For `String(10)` it is the same story. "In SQL, corresponds to VARCHAR" (which will be a `TEXT` at the end for SQLite database)

source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.String